# MULTIPASS yields dnsmasq error at launch. What can I do?

Tags: 20.04, budgie, dnsmasq, multipass

I just installed Multipass (Canonical's virtual machine manager) on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.
When I run the [Multipass launch](https://multipass.run/docs/launch-command) command, I get:

```
[error] [dnsmasq] Process operation timed out
launch failed: Multipass dnsmasq failed to start: program: dnsmasq; error: Process operation timed out
```

When I run `dnsmasq` on it's own I see:

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Permission denied
```

The Multipass website only has troubleshooting tips for MacOS and Windows, oddly.  However, in the [MacOS troubleshooter](https://multipass.run/docs/troubleshooting-networking-on-macos) it states:

> The built-in DNS server should be “mDNSResponder” which binds to localhost on port 53.

I've been reading about dnsmasq, port 53, network manager and stuff like that but the dots are not connecting for me.

Comment: The following information is also available, have you checked this one? It's a little different than your problem, but very similar, I think it's a conflict with the existing dns running on MacOS. Troubleshooting networking on macOS - Multipass / Documentation - Ubuntu Community Hub
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/troubleshooting-networking-on-macos/12901

Comment: @YANNO Thanks.  That article does mention that "another dnsmasq process bound to localhost port 53" is "known to interfere with Multipass".  I'd say that is my issue.  And, I still am at a loss for how to proceed.